# View and create routes with netsh

Tags: windows-7, networking

In some previous versions of MS Windows, IP protocol static routes could be managed using commands to the netsh program. Those commands have changed.

Is there still a way to manage routes with netsh?

If not, what would be the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are still under `netsh interface`, only the *interface ip* context has been renamed to *interface ipv4*.

```
netsh> interface ipv4
netsh interface ipv4> add route
```

See documentation for [`ipv4`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753156(v=WS.10).aspx)and [`ipv6`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731521(v=WS.10).aspx) on Microsoft.

In addition to `netsh`, some Windows NT versions have a `route` command:

```
C:\> route print
C:\> route add
```